# How to prove Hom$(U,V)\cong U^∗ \otimes V$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know this result is well-known, but could some one give me some help with this proof - or some reference? Thank you.

Also, I have taken second year linear algebra (Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right), but I still find much trouble understanding Hom(U,V), like what is its basis; and no idea about tensor product.

So should I consider "a third year linear algebra"? Though there is not really a course named so - but is there a course or book I should read after Axler? Or I can learn more about these in some other course, like functional analysis? Is Representation theory related/necessary at this level?

Thanks!

Comment: If $\phi \in U^*$ and $v \in V$, try the map $\phi\otimes v \mapsto \phi(\cdot) v$.

Comment: Thanks @TylerHolden - I haven't gotten it yet, could you give me more details?

Comment: @MathSnail I think the ball is in your court: can you give *us* details about *where you are stuck* using Tyler's hint?

Comment: Thanks rschwieb. I suppose to construct a map between $\text{Hom}(U,V)$ and $U^* \otimes V$ right? So the map @TylerHolden gives is from $U^* \otimes V$ to $\text{Hom}(U,V)$? I couldn't see why $\phi(\cdot)v$ is an element of $\text{Hom}(U,V)$. Thanks!

Comment: @rschwieb Though I do see that $\phi(\cdot)$ is an element of Hom($U,V$)...

Answer (score 3):

As Tyler writes, the map which is defined on decomposable tensors by
$$\phi \otimes v \mapsto (u \mapsto \phi(u) v)$$ is an isomorphism---at least, *when $U$ and $V$ are finite dimensional*. To see this, note that if $u_1^*,\dots,u_m^*$ is a basis for $U^*$ and $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is a basis for $V$, then the tensors $u_i^* \otimes v_j$ are a basis of the tensor space $U^* \otimes V$, and these map to the matrix units, which are a basis of the Hom space $\mathrm{Hom}(U,V)$.

[In fact, the same argument works assuming only that $U$ is finite dimensional, and the result is false, without imposing more structure, if $U$ is infinite dimensional.]

Comment: Your last statement is somewhat contradictory.  If $U$ is finite dimensional and $V$ is infinite dimensional you say both that it works and that it doesn't work.

Comment: Oops, of course I meant $U$ infinite dimensional! I'll edit. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: My understanding is that the result is true if $U$ *or* $V$ is finite dimensional, because in either case one can define a splitting $\hom(U, V) \to U^\ast \otimes V$.  Do you have an example of $U$ infinite dim and $V$ finite dim that shows it doesn't work?

Comment: You are right that it's true if *either* is finite dimensional. You could argue as you say, or use the fact that it's obvious if either if one-dimensional, and use (finite) bi-additivity of both functors.

Answer (score 2):

As noted already in the comments, define

$$\phi: U^*\otimes V\to \text{Hom}(U,V)\;\;\text{by}\;\;\phi(f\otimes v)(u):=f(u)v\,,\,\,\text{and extend def. by linearity}$$

I'll leave it to you to check this is actually a homomorphism between vector spaces, but for example

$$\phi\left(t\sum_{k=1}^rf_k\otimes v_k\right)(u)=\phi\left(\sum_{k=1}^rf_k\otimes (tv_k)\right)(u):=\sum_{k=1}^rf_k(u)(tv_k)=t\sum_{k=1}^rf_k(u)v_k=\ldots$$

with, of course, $\,t\in\Bbb F=$ the definition field.

As an idea for the isomorphism thingy,  check that

$$\dim_{\Bbb F}\text{Hom}(U^*,V)=\dim_{\Bbb F}U^*\cdot\dim_{\Bbb F}V=\dim_{\Bbb F}U^*\otimes V$$

so that you only need to prove the above map is either injective or surjective (because the finite dimensions). Choose basis $\,A=\{u_1,...,u_n\}\;,\;\{v_1,...,v_m\}\;$ of $\,U,V\;$ resp., and let $\,\{f_1,...,f_n\}\,$ be *the dual basis* of $\,A\,$ above in $\,U^*\,$ , meaning: $\,f_i(u_j)=\delta_{ij}:=$ the delta of Kronecker, then

$$\phi\left(f_i\otimes v_k\right)(u_j):=f_i(u_j)v_k=\delta_{ij}v_k$$

Check the above makes the map $\,\phi\,$ surjective and thus automatically an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks very much. I am not sure about I couldn't see why ϕ(⋅)v is an element of Hom(U,V).

Comment: To me, it is more like that $\phi(\cdot)$ is an element of Hom($U,V$), paring with an element $v$ in the vector space $V$. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Check that the output is $\,\phi(u)v\;,\;\;\phi(u)\in\Bbb F\;,\;\;v\in V\,$ , so this is the product of a scalar and a vector in $\,V\,$ and thus the outcome is in $\,V\,$...in fact, this is one of the most basic linear transformations in a linear space: a vector times a scalar!

Comment: Thank you Don. When I try to prove $$\phi: U^*\otimes V\to \text{Hom}(U,V)\;\;\text{by}\;\;\phi(f\otimes v)(u):=f(u)v$$ is a homomorphism between vector spaces, I get lost at the operations of $U^*\otimes V$ and $\text{Hom}(U,V)$ - what are the operations?